# How is abstraction an advantage of OOP if it can also be done procedurally?

Tags: c++, oop, procedural-programming

I am completely new to programming and don't understand why abstraction is an advantage of OOP. All sites mention abstraction as one of the key advantages of OOP but this can be achieved procedurally also.

If I write:

```
int add(int x, int y){
   return x + y;
}

int main() {
   int z = add(3,4);
}
```

Abstraction is used to hide background details or any unnecessary implementation about the data so that users only see the required information, so isn't this also abstraction as the user can use "add" without knowing how it works? Did I get the idea of abstraction wrong because this is basically the only definition I got about abstraction online? If not then why is it an "advantage" if you can achieve it without OOP?

Comment: If you meet someone that tells you that "OOP" and "abstraction" can only be used in a few selected languages, then you can tell them they're wrong. You can apply OOP principles and abstraction to almost any language.

Comment: Yes, a function is an example of abstraction.

Comment: "Abstraction" is an incredibly broad term that encompasses far, far more than just "callers of code don't have to be aware of implementation detail".

Comment: What you're showing here is an abstraction yes. But you can do much more complicated abstractions than that with OOP. You can abstract more. It's not as binary as abstraction or no abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not bad, but it is a bit naive. It's quite obvious that you're asking about topics quite ahead of you. Good thing you're curious though. I mean no offense.

Abstraction is not a binary thing that a language supports or not. Languages does more or less abstraction, but all languages are abstractions above assembly language. I like C a lot, but it's not good for abstractions.

Abstraction is a very broad thing. Your question is a bit like what the purpose of wind instruments is since a guitar "can produce sound". It's not at all intended to insinuate that this would be a stupid question. I'm only mentioning it to illustrate how broad the topic of abstraction is. Creating a simple function is basically a few molecules on the top of the iceberg.

Just to show a quick and VERY simple example:

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual double area();
};

class Triangle : public Shape {
private:
    double base, height;

public:
    double area() { return base*height/2.0; }
};

class Square : public Shape {
private:
    double side;

public:
    double area() { return side*side; }
};

int main() {
    // This is technically not correct, since arrays does not support 
    // polymorphism, but it's a small detail and not very relevant
    // since the point is still demonstrated.
    Shape shapes = new Shape[10];

    // Init code   

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        std::cout << "Area: " << shapes[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

That's a level of abstraction that would be extremely messy to achieve in C. And then, this is not even a very complex example. It's as basic as it goes when it comes to show OOP.

Excuse my C++ code. All I know from C++, I learned 20 years ago. So it's probably a bit old school. Maybe it doesn't even compile, but it's just to show the abstraction. And it's aimed towards someone who comes from C.

Comment: There are some subtleties with object slicing where you would want to change around how you write the calling code to do this, but it still illustrates the point.

Comment: Arrays do not support polymorphism. Maybe change the example to use a pointer?

Comment: Re “all languages are abstractions above assembly language”: When you have to use an instruction the assembler does not know about yet and won’t be in hardware for a year or so (one cost of being on the bleeding edge), you will know assembly language has abstractions too.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't say assembly does not have abstractions?